# robot_localization package position output is the same as input absolute pose

Tags: robot-localization, ekf, sensor-fusion

Hello my question is whether this type of output is a proper output? I fuse absolute pose from slam and fuse linear velocity from wheel odometry, but the filter output position data is the same as the position data from slam regarding the covariance matrix value from both input source. Is this normal? though if position data from slam got blocked the filter still provide data it got from wheel odometry.

Setup:
Ubuntu 18.04
Ros melodic

The "odom_cov_ukf" is from wheel odometry of my differential drive robot and "vo_cov_ukf" is from my slam
this is my configuration.

[image]

Comment: Welcome at RSE. First of all, please don't post pictures from text. Second, please give more information of your setup, configuration files, ROS distribution etc

Comment: You seem to have two accounts: [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/36874/ruj) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/36876/rui). You can merge the accounts, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/280335). It is rather irregular to gain reputation from suggesting edits to your own posts (as well as posting answers) from a different account..

Comment: Please include your full EKF config (as text), as well as one sample message from every sensor input.